# Async method execution flow that has to deal a simple CPU bound operation

Tags: c#, webapi

```
public class Car
    {
        public int TyresCount { get; set; }
        public int SpareTyreCount { get; set; }
        public int FrontTyres { get; set; }
        public int RearTyres { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarAssembly
    {

        public async Task<Car> Process(Car car)
        {
            car = await AssembleFrameAsync(car);
            //Option A
            SetTyreCount(car);
            //or Option B
            SetTireCountNonStatic(car);
            //or Option C
            await Task.Run(() => SetTyreCountAsync(car));
            car = await AssembleEngineAsync(car);
            return car;
        }

        public async Task<Car> AssembleFrame(Car car)
        {
            car = await httpclient.GetAsync("GetFrame");
            return car;
        }

        //Option A
        private static void SetTyreCount(Car car)
        {
            car.TyresCount = car.FrontTyres + car.RearTyres;
            car.SpareTyreCount = 1;
        }

        //Option B
        public void SetTyreCountNonStatic(Car car)
        {
            car.TyresCount = car.FrontTyres + car.RearTyres;
            car.SpareTyreCount = 1;
        }

        //Option C
        public void SetTyreCountAsync(Car car)
        {
            car.TyresCount = car.FrontTyres + car.RearTyres;
            car.SpareTyreCount = 1;
        }
        public async Task<Car> AssembleEngineAsync(Car car)
        {
            car = await httpclient.postAsync("assembleEngine");
            return car;
        }
    }
```

I have this class **CarAssembly** that has the method **Process**, that calls an async method **AssembleFrame** and then it has to call another method to **GetTyreCount** which is very simple method to get the count, as mentioned above with the above 3 options OptionA, OptionB, OptionC which is the right way to call this simple CPU bound method. Even if the options what I stated is not right, please provide your thoughts what's the right approach. Assume it's class execution in a WebAPI(no UI)

Comment: Why does **Get**TyreCount **set** the values on the car?

Comment: You should definitely *not* use `Task.Run` unless the method you are calling is very long-running and would interfere with the execution of your code. Static vs non-static doesn't matter so much, but since the method doesn't use any class members, I would probably prefer static for something of that nature.

Comment: not A, B and C are the same except for the name, better name be "SetTireCount", as well its not  'Async' and Get, implies that it return something of which it doesn't (void). they all work.... but why have  a static version? option c is wrong as you wrapping a non Async, so the most correct is B with a name change to something like  "SetTireCount"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On WebAPI, you should use options A or B. Use option A if you don't need access to instance variables (such as a logger). Use option B if you do.

As a general rule, [do not use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net).